# Where can I find the layout of login screen of GDM default theme?

Tags: gnome, login-screen, gdm

I'll explain it better. I want to change some colors, fonts and what I want of the default login screen. I like it and I don't want to change it, but I changed the background and now some texts are unreadable. I know these settings are located in the gdm3.css CSS file and I can modify it well. The problem is I don't know which css class is for which item of the login screen. If I can know this I will not have any type of problems.
I have tried to google and search in more ways but I didn't find anything.

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.